React Native Gifted Charts - Is there a way to adjust data point label components so that they stay within the screen?
I'm using the line graph component to display values over time. I'm signifying the largest and smallest values with a data label like so:
overlapping data label
As you can see, if the data label is at the edge of the screen, it will overlap and be unreadable.
I cannot simply get the first and last indexes and adjust the data label for these, as the 2nd to last, 3rd to last, etc. will also overlap the screen edge, and the number of data points is variable so I couldn't just hardcode values.
Here I tried making the label invisible, then using handleLayout to measure the position of the datapointlabel, before saving that position with Redux.
            export const DataPointLabelComponentLayoutSetter = (value: number, isMax: boolean, currencyType: string) => {
    const handleLayout = (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
        event.persist(); // Prevent the event from being reused
        event.currentTarget?.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
            if (isMax === true) {
                store.dispatch(setCoinGraphDataLabelPropsMax({ x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY, value, isMax }));
            } else if (isMax === false) {
                store.dispatch(setCoinGraphDataLabelPropsMin({ x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY, value, isMax }));
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <View style={[styles.labelContainer, { opacity: 0 }]} onLayout={handleLayout}>
            {!isMax && <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-up" color={"white"} size={10} />}
            <Text style={styles.labelText}>{convertToCurrencyFormat(value, currencyType)}</Text>
            {isMax && <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-down" color={"white"} size={10} />}
        </View>
    );
};

I then sent this to a secondary label on top that adjusts the position away from the edge of the screen, but this was buggy and sometimes wouldn't update the position - I guess this had something to do with Redux but it already felt hacky so I wasn't surprised it didn't work.
    const dataLabelPropsMax = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.coinGraphDataLabelProps?.coinGraphDataLabelPropsMax);
    const dataLabelPropsMin = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.coinGraphDataLabelProps?.coinGraphDataLabelPropsMin);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <LineChart
                ...
            />
            {dataLabelPropsMax && dataLabelPropsMin && (
                <>
                    <DataPointLabelComponent currencyType={currencyType} dataPointLabelProps={dataLabelPropsMax} />
                    <DataPointLabelComponent currencyType={currencyType} dataPointLabelProps={dataLabelPropsMin} />
                </>
            )}
        </View>
    );

How can I get around this problem?

You can get the first and last (or the first few and the last few) indices even if the number of data points is variable.
The first few indices will always be 0,1,2...
The last few indices will always be data.length-1, data.length-2, data.length-3...
Once you have the required indices, you can conditionally shift their data point labels towards left or right to avoid truncation.
